# CommandT installation problems on windows

Tags: vim

After completing all installation steps for the CommandT plugin, I get the error `command-t.vim could not load the C extension` when starting it.  The ComamndT troubleshooting section gives this advice:

```
If a problem occurs the first thing you should do is inspect the output of:

  ruby extconf.rb
  make

During the installation, and:

  vim --version

And compare the compilation and linker flags that were passed to the
extension and to Vim itself when they were built. If the Ruby-related
flags or architecture flags are different then it is likely that something
has changed in your Ruby environment and the extension may not work until
you eliminate the discrepancy.
```

And it does indeed seem that there is discrepancy for me.

Output from `make` suggests cygwin's gcc is using ruby 1.8:

```
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I. -DHA
VE_RUBY_H    -g -O2    -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -c ext.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I. -DHA
VE_RUBY_H    -g -O2    -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -c match.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I. -DHA
VE_RUBY_H    -g -O2    -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -c matcher.c

gcc -shared -s -o ext.so ext.o match.o matcher.o -L. -L/usr/lib -L.  -Wl,--enabl
e-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import,--export-all   -lruby  -ldl -lcrypt
```

Output from vim's `:version` contains this output:

```
-DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=191 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby191.dll\"
```

The troubleshooting guide suggests using a combination of Vim 7.2, Ruby 1.8.7-p299, and DevKit 3.4.5r3-20091110.  However this is not a good solution for me for a number of reasons:

1. I'm using Vim 7.3 and would like to continue doing so.
2. Ruby 1.9.3 is installed on my system, and I need it in my PATH for other projects.

So is there any way to get this working, while keeping the latest version of ruby and the latest version of vim?

## UPDATE

Having followed AndrewMarshall's advice, I installed Ruby191 and DevKit-4.5.0-20100819-1536-sfx.exe according to [this tutorial](https://github.com/SolutionYogi/VimSetup/blob/master/software/README.txt) and ran `ruby extconf.rb` through that version.  The `make` cmd executed successfully with this output:

```
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby191/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby191/include/ruby-1
.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby191/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RUBY_H    -O2 -g -
Wall -Wno-parentheses   -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -o ext.o -c
 ext.c
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby191/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby191/include/ruby-1
.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby191/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RUBY_H    -O2 -g -
Wall -Wno-parentheses   -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -o match.o
-c match.c
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby191/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby191/include/ruby-1
.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby191/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RUBY_H    -O2 -g -
Wall -Wno-parentheses   -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -o matcher.
o -c matcher.c
gcc -shared -s -o ext.so ext.o match.o matcher.o -L. -LC:/Ruby191/lib -L.  -Wl,-
-enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import   -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2
_32
```

and running `:CommandT` in vim works now, but as soon as I start typing to search for a file, and then hit enter to select and open it, I get this:
[image: Vim Crashing]

Comment: The Ruby version used when running `ruby extconf.rb` must match the Ruby version that Vim was compiled with.

Comment: To follow @AndrewMarshall advice you should change `ruby` command here. If it were my Gentoo I would say you should replace `ruby extconf.rb` with `ruby19 extconf.rb`. But I do not know how is it installed on windows, maybe you need a full path here.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, I have followed your advice and was able to install CommandT, but it crashes vim now.  Please see update to the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not a real answer but you may wanna try [ctrlp](http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/) instead.

- written in `vimscript` (no dependency, no compiling)
- as fast as `CommandT` (subjective to me)
- has probably more features than `CommandT` (does `CommandT` have *most recent file*?)

there is also the good old [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) which I haven't tried. seems like it hasn't got updated for about 2 years but it may still be working.

Comment: This is, in fact, what I ended up doing a few days ago.  ctrlp is great.  Even if cmdT is better in some ways, no way it's worth all this headache.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully installed newest `command-t` on vim 8.0 on windows 10. And I find this question when I'm working on it so I'm gonna post my solution although it's a little late.

Ruby version for vim 8.0 is Ruby 2.2. So  download and install `Ruby 2.2` and `Ruby Devkit` (remember to execute `ruby dk.rb init` and `ruby dk.rb install` for `devkit` ).

Then I follow the command-t instruction to execute `ruby extconf.conf`, but it failed -- it output `You have to install development tools first.` even though I did install it:

I googled this issue find [RubyInstaller wiki](https://github.com/OneClick/RubyInstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) says that I should execute this command by add `-rdevkit` and I did it. It succeed when I execute `ruby -rdevkit extconf.rb` but failed when `make`. So I googled again and find another way to compile it:

`rake make -rdevkit`

And it worked. Here is my screenshot:

[image]